# RSA fingerprint change every time a new build is started

Tags: android, docker, adb, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a CI pipeline to build my android app and run instrumented test using gitlab pipelines. My gitlab runner is a ubuntu 16.04 machine running each build in a docker container. I have a physical android device connected via USB to my gitlab runner.

Recently, every time a new build is triggered, I am prompted to allow the RSA fingerprint for the USB device on my android target. The problem is that the fingerprint changes with every build.

I suspect that this is because a new container is created every time a build start.

How can I automatically accept the new fingerprint or prevent the fingerprint from changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make contents of `$HOME/.android/adbkey` and `$HOME/.android/adbkey.pub` persistent between the runs by mapping the folder or just re-creating the files inside every container instance.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I just added both file to my docker image.