# ADB over SSH causing RSA Key change

Tags: ssh, android-emulator, automated-tests, adb, rsa

So what I have is a CI server going through testing remotely by connecting to a target device with all necessary android testing components installed, setting up the repo, compiling it, then running the tests on it.

I've noticed that the RSA fingerprints always reset, and never use the same ones from $HOME/.android/

So that forces me to basically manually accept the key on the running emulator to have the tests run in the first place.

It's clear why this is bad, is there a way to accept these keys by the emulator automatically? or through cmd? Or what do I need to do with the keys so that I don't get forced to set them up every single time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47799984/1778421

Comment: I've already seen this. 
I am connecting over through ssh to a system that's already set up. 
on the other hand, the guy is using docker containers. 
Two different problems because my system doesn't reset outside of deleting the repo folder created for the testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, and all it took to make it work was restarting the target system.

The system set up is a mac mini, with multiple users. 
They separately had android studio installed and running it. 
It seems as though android studio was already using the main adb so it had to start up a new instance of the adb with its very own set of RSA fingerprint.

Make sure that only one instance of the adb is running at a time on the same machine.